# Is it faster to use aggregation or manually filter through data with nodejs and mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm at a crossroads trying to decide what methodology to use. Basically, I have a mongodb collection and i want to query it with specific params provided by the user, then i want to group the response according to the value of some of those parameters. For example, let's say my collection is animals and if i query all animals i get something like this

```
[
    {type:"Dog",age:3,name:"Kahla"},
    {type:"Cat",age:6,name:"mimi"},
    ...
]
```

Now i would like to return to the user a response that is grouped by the animal type, so that i end up with something like

```
{
    Dogs: [...dog docs],
    Cats: [...cat docs],
    Cows: [...],
}
```

So basically I have 2 ways of doing this. One is to just use `Model.find()` and fetch all the animals that match my specific queries, such as age or any other field, and then manually filter and format my json response before sending it back to the user with `res.json({})` (im using express btw)

Or I can use mongo's aggregate framework and `$group` to do this at the query level, hence returning from the DB an already grouped response to my request. The only inconvenience I've found with this so far with this is how the response is formatted, and ends up looking more something like this

```
[
    {
        "_id":"Dog",
        "docs":[{dog docs...}]
    },
    {
        "_id":"Cat",
        "docs":[{...}]
    }
]
```

The overall result is BASICALLY the same, but the formatting of the response is quite different, and my front end client needs to adjust to how Im sending the response. I don't really like the array of objects from the aggregation, and prefer a json-like object response with key names correponding to the arrays as I see fit.

So the real question here is whether there is one significant advantage of one way over the other? Is the aggregation framework so fast that it will scale well if my collection grows to huge numbers? Is filtering through the data with javascript and mapping the response so I can shape it to my liking a very inefficient process, and hence it's better to use aggregation and adapt the front end to this response shape?

Comment: The MQL (Mongo Query Language) and Aggregation framework return a valid JSON. You can use a $projection stage to format (re-shape) you data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm considering that by `Faster` you meant the least time to serve a request. That said, let's divide the time required to process your request:

- Asynchronous Operations (Network Operations, File read/write etc)
- Synchronous Operations

Synchronous operations are usually much more faster than the Asynchronous ones.(This also depends on the nature of the operation and the amount of data being processed). For example, if you loop over an iterable(e.g. Array, Map etc) which has a length of less than 1000 it won't take more than a few milliseconds.

On the other hand, Asynchronous operations takes more times. For example, if you run an HTTP request it would take couple of milliseconds to get the response.

When you are querying on the MongoDB with mongoose, it's an asynchronous call and it will take more time. So, if you run more queries to Database it will make your API slower. MongoDB Aggregation can help you reducing the total number of queries which may help you to make APIs faster. But the problem is, Aggregations are usually slower than normal `find` requests.

The summary is, if you can manually filter data without adding any DB query it's going to be faster.

Comment: thanks, even if i want to manually filter the data, first i need to query it, and then iterate through it and format a response as i see fit. So i can't escape at least one db query. So it's basically what's less intensive; db query + iterations and filtering OR one db query with aggregation. Your comparison of sync vs async is a useful consideration, thanks!

Comment: I believe a `find` query with iteration will be faster than an aggregation query.